# GKGameCenterViewController wont dismiss?

Tags: ios, iphone, game-center, sprite-kit

I dont get it please help i DONT get a log when i hit done

```
 - (IBAction)loadScores:(id)sender {
GKGameCenterViewController* gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
// gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

 -(void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController*)gameCenterViewController {
NSLog(@"rfffff");
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
[vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: still stuck on it tried using the actual view controller too no luck

Comment: Why have you commented this line: `// gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have commented the delegates of the `GKGameCenterViewController`. This means all the delegate methods will not be called like the one that dismisses the view controller. So I suggest you uncomment this line and then run the code and see.

Comment: I just woke up thinking the same thing. It depreciated in ios 7 thats why I did it